# Python Pip Package with React Frontend

Tags: python, reactjs, pip, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I have a project where a Flask app is being installed as a Pip Package and can be ran using a command. The project is using a `pyproject.toml` and a `MANIFEST.IN` to specify how the project should be bundled.

I would like to now add a static React frontend to this project. The frontend is built using Webpack so that Flask can serve the outputted `index.html`.

What would be the best way for the React frontend to be bundled in the Pip Package? Does the `dist` folder with the static assets need to be committed and uploaded to GitHub? Or is it possible for the build command to be ran while Pip is bundling the package (such as within the `pyproject.toml`)?

Comment: "*Does the `dist` folder with the static assets need to be committed and uploaded to GitHub?*: Very much depends on what is better for your users. What do you want for a user to clone? Is it better for a user to clone with the compiled files or build them themselves?

Comment: "*…is it possible for the build command to be ran while Pip is bundling the package…*" It's possible with `setup.py` but not with `pyproject.toml`